# Chrome interprets margin-top different from Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I do realize this question exists in multiple instances on SO, but the answers come down to 'reset the CSS' and I've already done that so I'm puzzled by this.

In the following image, you will see that the words "some basic member" and "some premium member" are higher by 1 or 2 pixels in Chrome compared to Firefox (relative to the "B" icon).

[image: Firefox VS Chrome]

You can also see in the image what "inspect element" comes up with for the "some basic member" link. What may be of interest is that the `margin-top` is faded in Chrome's console, and in Firefox's it doesn't appear at all!

This is a responsive design with Bootstrap. This particular example is under `@media (max-width: 340px)`. When I uncheck the `margin-top` in Chrome, the link moves further up because it inherits the style from `@media (max-width: 420px)`.

However, the margin issue isn't specific to the example when width is less than 340px, it's the same on any width. The Firefox version is correct and the Chrome version is off by a little.

Any idea what the cause may be and how I can fix it?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24L7z2mu/3/

Comment: Look in source code. If something isn't in inspector of one browser it dosen't mean that it isn't there at all. You can write css to affect only one browser in many different ways. What shows after clicking minestyle.css link?

Comment: Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @JamieBarker Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/24L7z2mu/3/

Comment: @Kinga The CSS file just defines `font-size` and `margin-top` for the element, there's nothing browser-specific about it...you can see the full CSS in the fiddle.

Comment: @jovan but i see it in your jsfiddle:
@ media (max-width: 340px) {
.menu-list > li > a {
 ....

.league_name,.league_score{
 font-size: 17px;
 margin-top: 16px;
}
It is there then how you expect that Chrome will not respect it?

Comment: @jovan firebug on ff shows it too http://i.imgur.com/tpwguPA.png My diagnosis of your problem is cache.

Comment: @Kinga The question is, why does it display different in Firefox and Chrome. I *want* them to both obey the rule. In the same way. But they don't, as you can see.

Comment: @jovan Check your jsfiddle they display exactly the same. http://imgur.com/rSM7UsU

Comment: @Kinga They do not display the same, if you use a ruler (or something similar) you will see the Chrome version is higher by about 2px.

Comment: @JamieBarker nope http://imgur.com/zlPzaUQ

Comment: @Kinga I have tested on Windows and Android. Are you perhaps trying this on iOS?

Comment: @jovan both. this is win screenshot http://imgur.com/Yh94qvf

Comment: @Kinga This is irrelevant now, but you're wrong. In the windows screenshot, the one on the left has width >420px so different styles apply, as you see the fonts are larger.

Comment: @jovan pleas do the screenshot from your fiddle yourself go to photoshop  draw line from one side to another end ok from fiddle not form your app... k??

Comment: I don't see how it matters any more, but here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107503233/nope.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use margin to align things up.

If you want the text to be vertically centered to the image, you can achieve this with `display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;`

```
.league_type_icon, .item_type_icon {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.league_name {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #211b18;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

With this method you can completely get rid of the margin in your `@media` queries

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/24L7z2mu/5/)

Comment: Thanks, that is certainly a better solution. But, out of curiosity, any idea what could be causing the problem with margin-top? Could it have to do with line-height perhaps?

Comment: perhaps, but in my experience there's nearly always some minor differences like that between browsers. Heck, IE6 **doubled** `margin-left` on things floated left. Use margin for spacing only. All alignment of things can be achieved using much better means, and you'll end up with far less CSS code!